# Deny access to symlinked source

Tags: .htaccess

I have `foo/bar.txt` which should be 403 and I also have `foo-hashed/hash/bar.txt` which is a symlink to `foo/bar.txt` and should be accessible. `foo/.htaccess` contains

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

which is all good but I can't get the hashed file to be accessible. I tried all sorts of variants of `Options FollowSymLinks` in `foo`, in `foo-hashed` without much success.

Comment: AllowOverride All or AllowOverride None?

Comment: AllowOverride All.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is `foo/.htaccess`

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from env=symlink
```

This is `foo-hashed/.htaccess`

```
SetEnv symlink=1
```

Edit: this is a working solution.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: This *is* the complete answer.

Comment: This seems needlessly convoluted. `Deny from all` in the root - and `Options FollowSymLinks, Allow from all` in the foo-hashed folder.